How can I convert a string to random multi case register string in Kotlin?
Example:
Input:
val someString: String = "Quam, lorem eleifend efficitur matti"
Output:
val randomMultiRegisterString = "QUaM, lOrEm elEIFeNd eFFiCITur matTI"
I haven't come to any decision yet((( I hope for your advice

It's strange why do you need it:)
You can iterate through string chars, apply Random.nextBoolean to every symbol and join result to new string with random cases
import kotlin.random.Random

fun toRandomMultiCaseRegister(input: String): String {
    return input.map { char ->
        if (Random.nextBoolean()) char.uppercaseChar() else char.lowercaseChar()
    }.joinToString("")
}

https://pl.kotl.in/civbg-P2P

This is a good, simple approach.  Tweaks you might consider to make it more concise: making it an extension function on String; using an expression body; using it instead of naming the lambda param; and importing Random.nextBoolean instead of Random.

Don't think string extension is good, but it's possible to define such way fun String.randomcaseChar(): String = map { if (Random.nextBoolean()) it.uppercaseChar() else it.lowercaseChar() }.joinToString("")
